# How can I use web api controller to receive complex type that includes an image from HTTPPost via POSTMAN

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I want to receive a complex type user which has the attributes: username, password, and profilePicture which is type File. How would the code of my api controller look like? 
This is what I have so far just for receiving image files. How can I modify the function or write a new function to accept type User, which contains a file and other properties.

```
public void UploadFile()
{
    var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ?
           HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //has file
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below sample code

// This is the model class

```
    public class UserModel
    {
       public String Username { get; set; }
        public String Password { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase Userfile { get; set; }
    }
```

// This is controller action method, you can also use Request.Files here

```
    [HttpPost]
    public String UploadFile(UserModel user)
    {
        // you'll get posted file in user.Userfile
        return user.Username;
    }
```

//  This is the HTML form used to post data

```
    <form action="/Home/UploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
       <input name="Username" type="text" />
       <input name="Password" type="password" />
       <input type="file" name="Userfile" />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm doing the server side for both web and mobile(android). This is very useful for the web. Do you also know how I can receive complex type with images from android client via Postman?

Comment: This should also work file when making a request using postman or any httpclient, also if possible can you please provide more details on how you are posting your request.